# Click Noise after sending Audio Data to server

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, wav

I am trying to record sound and sent it to server.
when I record sound there is no clicking noise.but after sending server I am getting a click sound.

As server is expecting raw wav stream without any “RIFF” headers, I am removing header and send it to the server 
 Here is my code

```
var newAudioData = audioData.advanced(by: 44)
```

I am removing 44 Byte from the front of original buffer and send newAudioData to server.  
How that click sound is produced?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're not removing any PCM data? Removing any arbitrary data could lead to misaligned phase/waveform and could produce a click. Another idea: are you sure you're reconstructing the data properly on the server? Switched data frames could also misalign the waveform.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Is there any way efficient way to remove RIFF header from audio data?